# mapping day of week to number python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, conditional-statements

I need to iterate through a dataframe and generate a column that transposes a weekday into its related number.

I've came up with the following:

```
 inputData['DOW'] = ""
    for i in range(0,len(inputData)):
        if 'Sunday' in inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week']:
            inputData.iloc[i]['DOW']=1
        elif 'Monday' in inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week']:
           inputData.iloc[i]['DOW']=2
        elif 'Tuesday' in inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week']:
           inputData.iloc[i]['DOW']=3
        elif 'Wednesday' in inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week']:
           inputData.iloc[i]['DOW']=4
        elif 'Thursday' in inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week']:
            inputData.iloc[i]['DOW']=5
        elif 'Friday' in inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week']:
            inputData.iloc[i]['DOW']=6
        elif 'Saturday' in inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week']:
            inputData.iloc[i]['DOW']=7
```

But this gives me back the column "DOW" empty for all the rows... What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to break down why this is wrong - but it is on many levels. You can simply remap by using replace

```
import pandas as pd
mapping = {
    'Sunday': 0,
    'Monday': 1,
    'Tuesday': 2,
    'Wednesday': 3,
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Monday'], columns=['day_of_week'])
df['DOW'] = df['day_of_week'].replace(mapping)
df
```

output

```
    day_of_week DOW
0   Monday       1
1   Tuesday      2
2   Wednesday    3
3   Monday       1
```

To answer why your code did not work, I am still trying to figure this out myself.

But if you change to either of the following it seems to work

```
df.iloc[i, <index location of 'DOW' column>] = value
df.loc[i]['DOW'] = value
```

work because `.iloc` is integer based, and with loc you are using labels which are now consistent as outlined.

However, but it seems to work for all if statements if I only change one of your `if` statements to

```
inputData['DOW'] = ""

for i in range(0,len(inputData)):
#     print(inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week'] == 'Monday')

    if 'Sunday' == inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week']:
        inputData.iloc[i].DOW =1
        
    elif 'Monday' in inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week']:
        inputData.loc[i]['DOW'] = 2
    elif 'Tuesday' in inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week']:
       inputData.iloc[i].DOW=3
    elif 'Wednesday' in inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week']:
       inputData.iloc[i].DOW=4
    elif 'Thursday' in inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week']:
        inputData.iloc[i].DOW=5
    elif 'Friday' in inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week']:
        inputData.iloc[i].DOW=6
    elif 'Saturday' in inputData.iloc[i]['day_of_the_week']:
        inputData.iloc[i].DOW =7
```

Comment: interesting.. not sure yet why it returns an empty column though

Comment: but thanks for your answer.. it does the work and is way more concise than my approach